# Phone can't detect hotspot made by laptop (no, not the other way around)

Tags: linux, wi-fi

Trying to ssh to my laptop on my android phone with a network created by my laptop, but my android phone can't even see the wireless network I made. Will be carrying laptop around in a backpack. I don't need Internet access, tried refreshing phone, waiting, refreshing. Kali linux, android phone. I tried manually changing the channel. Is it maybe a frequency or channel issue?

Comment: How did you set up the access point? Can other computers connect to it?

Comment: other computers can see it, I just went to wireless connections and clicked make hotspot

Comment: In other words, via gui

Comment: Is this an ad-hoc network? Android cannot connect to ad-hoc networks.

Comment: Oh, yeah. I think it is. Why can't it?